# Joomla 1.5 error JHTMLlist not supported. File not found

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Unfortunately I see this error when I come back to an old Joomla 1.5 site.

```
JHTMLlist not supported. File not found.
```

Any solution for this problem?

Note that it is not updated. It is `1.5.23`

Is that a host related issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when you last updated your website, it must have missed that file.

First of all, download the [Joomla 1.5.0 - 1.5.26 patch](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16891/73383/Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package.tar.gz), upload to the root folder for you Joomla site, and extract. This might solve the problem, but if not then proceed by downloading the full [Joomla 1.5.26 package](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16890/73390/Joomla_1.5.26-Stable-Full_Package.zip), extract the "libraries" folder, then zip it up, upload to the root of your Joomla site in the FTP, and extract.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the file `ROOT/libraries/joomla/html/html/list.php` exists. If it does not then you need to upload one from the 1.5.23 package. If that does not fix your problem your best bet is to upgrade the site to the latest version of Joomla and see if that fixes the problem.

If you upgrade the site it should be automatically added - but I'm guessing by your post that for whatever reason you want to stick on 1.5.23 (N.B. All versions before 1.5.26 have a password security flaw that was fixed in 1.5.26).